# Limit Selected Divs to 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm currently selecting divs using this:

```
$(".gridbox").click(function () {

$(this).toggleClass("selected");

var isSelected = $(".gridbox.selected").length > 0;
        $("#button").toggle(isSelected);
    });
});
```

Is there any way I can limit the number of selected Divs to 5? I have tried:

```
var isSelected1 = $(".gridbox.selected").length < 3;

if (typeof isSelected1 !== 'undefined') {
alert("You have selected the maximum amount.");
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. If anyone has any ideas that'd be greatly appreciated!

Also I am presently selecting divs using:

```
<div onclick="clicked(this);" class="gridbox" id="1"></div>
```

Is there anything I can put anywhere to disable a certain ID from being selected?

Many thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to achieve what you are looking for:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/vPvKw/2/)

```
$(".gridbox:not(#disabled)").click(function () {
    if ($('.selected').length < 5 || $(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    }
});
```

It will limit the selection to 5 of any elements with class `.gridbox`. Not just the first 5 elements.

With usage of `:not`, you are unable to select an element with an `id` of "disabled" in this example.

Comment: That works perfect, thank you... Any ideas on the last part of the question? ;)

Comment: @BN83 You can explicitly exclude those using `:not` or `.not()`.

Comment: I still want to include them, just not allow the onclick to function as it would normally?

Comment: @BN83 See the updated example. Try selecting the last element - it has an `id` that is disabled from selection using `:not`

Comment: That's perfect thank you. Works in my test, but doesn't work when calling ID's from a database despite the code resulting the same output...

Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: Have sorted it now. Quick question, will the 'null' here:

    `$(".gridbox:not(null)").click(function () {`

cause any issues?

Comment: @BN83 It shouldn't. That will just prevent selection of an element with a tag `null`.. (`<null></null>`). There are no such tags, so it shouldn't cause any problems. Nonetheless, that doesn't mean such an element won't exist, it's just not likely to exist.

Comment: It won't exist in what i'm doing, so that's perfect. Thanks for your help.